# SQL:HOW TO TAKE SUBSTRING FOR QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a date as

1012009

i have to take the last sub-string 2009 in this date.

i need

```
2009
```

how to  take the last four digits in the coloum.

another example :

1032009

how to take the last four values 2009.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple string function:

```
SELECT RIGHT(INC_DATE, 4);
```

Comment: i have a colum name "INC_DATE" so i need to take sub string for all the coloum.

Comment: @AravinthaBashyam.c Is that a question or a statement? Can't tell.

Comment: i need answer for that question @Jack. i need to get values by last four digit in a coloum.

Comment: @AravinthaBashyam.c Just substitute the string with the column.